# JcomboBox not open on click and looses focus to the one next to it

Tags: netbeans, jcombobox

I wanted to create several dropdowns in the same GUI. I wanted to position them according to (x,y) and so i had to do: .setLayout(null); 
Not sure that this caused the problems.. however, when i try to click on any of the dropdowns, none of them gets open (simply nothing happens) and the other dropdown (there are few in the same page) gets focus. something real weird.. and i'm sure i didn't do it properly. I'm adding the code here. it is built from 3 different classes (each class in its own file). if anyone could run the code as it is and simply see the behaviour, maybe you'll know what is causing it. Just one more thing. the programs reads from a file called: Menu.txt. the file should be in the main dir of the netbeans projects and should have the following lines (exact lines):

File: Menu.txt  => Content:

Sushi Chips

1

20.0

Home Potetos

2

5.0

Soup Of Carrot

2

10.0

Hot Coffee

3

5.0

First File: ItemInMenu.java:

```
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ItemInMenu {
    int itemAmount, itemType, maxOrderAmountPerItem=50; 
    double itemPrice;
    String itemDisc;
    JComboBox itemComboBox;
    JCheckBox itemCheckBox;
    JTextField itemTextField; 

    public ItemInMenu(double itemPrice, String itemDisc, int itemType){

       this.itemCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Select Item");
       this.itemTextField = new JTextField();
       this.itemComboBox = new JComboBox();

       this.itemAmount = 0;
       this.itemType = itemType;
       this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
       this.itemDisc = itemDisc;

       //Add options to the dropdown (max 50 items to be ordered fro meach item)
       for (int i=0; i<maxOrderAmountPerItem; i++)
        {
         this.itemComboBox.addItem("Amount: " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Now Second Class. MainFunction.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import static java.lang.Integer.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class MainFunction {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int defaultWidth = 900, defaultHeight = 600;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Maman 13 - Question 1");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(defaultWidth,defaultHeight);

        //Adding the option not to resize the window.
        frame.setResizable(false);

        // Creation of a MyPanel object (which belongs to a class which inherits from JPanel class) //
        MyPanel newPanel = new MyPanel();

        //The .setLayot(null) is a line that disables the Layout manager and lets us position
        //items by ourselves (manual positioning of elements like Jcombo and such). We do
        //this line on the JPanel element (and not on the frame....).
        newPanel.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(newPanel);


        newPanel.readFromFile("Menu.txt");
        newPanel.printMenu();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

And the third file: MyPanel.java:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private ArrayList<ItemInMenu> itemsList = new ArrayList();
    private String fileName;

    public void readFromFile(String whichFile)
    {

         ItemInMenu newItem;
         int lineNumber, itemType = -1;
         Double itemPrice = -1.0;
         String currentLine, itemDisc = "";

         this.fileName = whichFile;

         //Now lets start reading this file...
         System.out.println("Reading from File: " + this.fileName);
         File myFile = new File(this.fileName);

         try {
             lineNumber = 0;
             Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(myFile);
             while (myScanner.hasNext())
                 {
                  lineNumber++;

                  currentLine = myScanner.nextLine();

                  System.out.println(currentLine);

                  if (lineNumber == 1)
                     {
                      itemDisc = currentLine;
                     }
                  else if (lineNumber == 2)
                      {
                       itemType = Integer.parseInt(currentLine);
                      }
                  else
                     {
                      itemPrice = Double.parseDouble(currentLine);

                      newItem = new ItemInMenu(itemPrice, itemDisc, itemType);
                      this.itemsList.add(newItem);

                      lineNumber = 0;
                     }

                  //System.out.println(currentLine);
                 }
             myScanner.close();
         }
         catch (FileNotFoundException ex)  
              {
               System.out.println("File Not Found!");
              }
        }

    public void printMenu(){

        for (ItemInMenu tmpVar : this.itemsList)
         {
          System.out.println("Printing Item Details:");   
          System.out.print("Item Disc: " + tmpVar.itemDisc + "\nItem Price: " + tmpVar.itemPrice + "\nItem Quantity: " + tmpVar.itemAmount + "\nItem Type: " + tmpVar.itemType + "\n\n");
         }
    }

    // The function who update the graphics of JPanel on every operation of the user (resize etc') //
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        int xLeftBox = 5, xCenterBox = 305, xRightBox = 605;
        int yLeftBox = 5, yCenterBox = 5, yRightBox = 5;
        int comboBoxWidth = 100, comboBoxHeight=25, spaceBetweenItems=100;



        super.paintComponent(g);

        //Now start drawing your own painting.
        for (ItemInMenu tmpVar : this.itemsList)
         {
          if (tmpVar.itemType == 1)
           {
            tmpVar.itemComboBox.setBounds(xLeftBox, yLeftBox, comboBoxWidth, comboBoxHeight);
            yLeftBox += spaceBetweenItems;
           }
          else if (tmpVar.itemType == 2)
                {
                 tmpVar.itemComboBox.setBounds(xCenterBox, yCenterBox, comboBoxWidth, comboBoxHeight);  
                 yCenterBox += spaceBetweenItems;
                }
               else
                {
                 tmpVar.itemComboBox.setBounds(xRightBox, yRightBox, comboBoxWidth, comboBoxHeight);
                 yRightBox += spaceBetweenItems;
                }

          tmpVar.itemComboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);

          tmpVar.itemComboBox.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        JComboBox combo = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
                        String currentQuantity = (String)combo.getSelectedItem();
                        System.out.println(currentQuantity);
                    }
                }            
          );

          this.add(tmpVar.itemComboBox);
         }
    }
}
```

Hope you'll be fine running it.. thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem was .add inside paintComponent function. it shouldn't be inside it since it adds lots of components all over again and it seems to cause problems.